# How can the name of a class be set automatically in a data attribute of an instance of that class in Python?

Tags: python, class, instance

How can the name of a class be set automatically in a data attribute of an instance of that class?

Here is some example code:

```
def workFunctionTest(**kwargs):
time.sleep(3)
return kwargs

def printHR(object):
    # dictionary
    if isinstance(object, dict):
        for key, value in sorted(object.items()):
            print u'{0}: {1}'.format(key, value)
    # list or tuple
    elif isinstance(object, list) or isinstance(object, tuple):
        for element in object:
            print element
    # other
    else:
        print object

class Job(object):
    def __init__(
        self,
        workFunction=workFunctionTest,
        workFunctionArguments={'testString': "hello world"},
        naturalLanguageString=None
        ):
        self.workFunction=workFunction
        self.workFunctionArguments=workFunctionArguments,
        self.naturalLanguageString=naturalLanguageString
    def printout(self):
        """
        This method prints a dictionary of all data attributes.
        """
        printHR(vars(self))

def main():
    job1=Job(
        workFunction=workFunctionTest,
        workFunctionArguments={'testString': "hello world"},
    )
    print("Is the object an instance of the class?")
    print isinstance(job1, Job)
    print("a printout generated by a method of the object:")
    job1.printout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

How could the end of the printout from this code be changed from this:

```
naturalLanguageString: None
workFunction: <function workFunctionTest at 0x7f435461ac80>
workFunctionArguments: ({'testString': 'hello world'},)
```

to this?:

```
naturalLanguageString: Job
workFunction: <function workFunctionTest at 0x7f435461ac80>
workFunctionArguments: ({'testString': 'hello world'},)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
self.naturalLanguageString = naturalLanguageString or self.__class__.__name__
```

this should work

if you do not pass the naturalLanguageString, it will be set by default with the class name

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `self.__class__.__name__`.

Comment: @adam It's OK to gently question the reason for a down vote (though not always productive). But it is absolutely unacceptable to be rude, and call people offensive names - no matter why.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
self.naturalLanguageString = self.__class__.__name__
```

As extra you can access ALL the class whit `self.__class__`

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for:

```
naturalLanguageString = type(self).__name__
```